# Python: plot multiple lines with the same variable as outcome

Tags: python, plot, python-3.6

for school I have to make a program that plots how many times you need to roll the dices to buy everything, with different amounts of cash each time. The script in order to calculate the roll of the dices etc is working properly, but I do not know how to make the plot. Here is my code to calculate for different amounts of starting cash:

```
money = [2500, 2000, 1500, 1000, 500, 0]
count = 0
for value in money:    
        while True:
            throw()
            piece.move(distance)
            count = count + 1
            start()
            buy()
            if (poslen) == 36:
                print("It took", count,"rolls.")
                plt()
                break
```

After that I wanted to make a plot which looks as follows:

```
def plt():
    money = [0,500,1000,1500,2000,2500]
    line0 = [count]
    line500 = [count]
    line1000 = [count]
    line1500 = [count]
    line2000 = [count]
    line2500 = [count]
    plt.xlabel("Amount of money")
    plt.ylabel("Amount of throws")
    plt.title("Throws with varying amounts of money")
    plt.plot(money, line0)
    plt.plot(money, line500)
    plt.plot(money, line1000)
    plt.plot(money, line1500)
    plt.plot(money, line2000)
    plt.plot(money, line2500)
    plt.show()
```

The variable count ofcourse varies every line(since it takes you more turns to buy stuff). So my questions is how do i print the correct Y value for each different line?(I hope my question is not to vague)

Comment: First hint - try to code everything english except it´s a functional-thing on UI which is called diffrent in your language. "Money in Geld" is equally for example - mybe use "Betrag in Beträge" (i´m guessing you understand german).

And how sould the plot be styled? simple lineprinting, a terminaltable, a UI-pop-up with a graph?

Comment: I edited it to english :) It should be simple lineprinting, showing the amount of throws for each amount of starting money. On the Y should be the throws and lines should go higher on the Y ass the amount of starting money decreases(since it takes you more time to accumulate money).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that supposedly already works, is incomplete: `poslen`, `throw`, `start`, `buy` and `distance` are missing, so I can't be exactly sure what you are doing there, but it looks like the structure of your loops is unnecessarily complicated. How about this instead?

```
for value in money:
    while not poslen == 36:
        throw()
        piece.move(distance)
        count = count + 1
        start()
        buy()
    print("Het duurde", count, "worpen voordat je alles had.")

plt()
```

It's also very suspicious `value` is not used anywhere. These mysteries do not help us understand what it is that your code is supposed to achieve.

As for your `plt` function, I suggest that you store your various counts in some container. Probably a dictionary. It's not clear to me exactly how you generate the data, but if you manage to get them into a dictionary (let's call it `line`), `plt` might look something like this:

```
def plt():
    for n, data in line.items():
        plt.plot(money, data, label=str(n))

    plt.xlabel("Amount of money")
    plt.ylabel("Amount of throws")
    plt.title("Throws with varying amounts of money")
```

Comment: Never thought about writing the for loop like that, thanks! It is way less complicated indeed. And yes is will definatelly use your tip mentioned about the plots!

Comment: @Kushan Note my edit about `value` being unused. It is likely that you will want to use `value` as the key in the dictionary, when you populate it. (If you find the answer helpful, don't forget to upvote and/or accept it.)

Comment: @Kushan Another edit: the `plt()` call does not belong inside the loop. You want to plot once you have collected all the data.